# show latest post from facebook on website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to retreive latest fb post from my fb page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

i am using the section to get code and here is my iframe code but its now working for me.

```
<div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcampinvention&amp;width=The+pixel+width+of+the+plugin&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
```

i also tried with `http://` but no luck

Comment: `width=The+pixel+width+of+the+plugin` – that does not look strange to you …?

Comment: i forgot to change when posting here ... but its not working when i change this text into 245px;

Comment: Well then show us where it is “not working”.

Comment: Its now working on my local server IIS.